# VS2012 x64 Cross Tool Command Prompt

Tags: build, 64-bit, devenv

I have a solution with many projects that currently requires me to first run the vs2012 x64 Cross Tool Command Prompt as administrator.  Then I load DevEnv and build the project from there.

How do I do this using the TFS Build Environment?
- Bruce

Comment: You should not need to do that.

Comment: @SLaks: Sometimes you don't have a choice. For example, MSBuild does not load references from the linkedConfigurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TFS Build Extensions from CodePlex, there is a build activity for DevEnv. Just swap the MSBuild activity for the DevEnv activity.

You could also create your own DevEnv activity, it is pretty straight-forward. You just need to use an `InvokeProcess` activity